# Limit number of files that can be uploaded by user (Laravel 5.3)

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have this scenario in my app, a user can only upload one journal in each edition (an edition contains many journals from many users) but a user can also tag another users to entitle them as one of the journal authors if needed (tagged user will still be able to upload a journal to the same edition with a journal where the user is tagged in as the author if the user haven't upload any journal yet). So far I managed to make this happen except for limiting the number of files that can be uploaded in each edition. Below are my migrations :

Edition table :

```
class CreateTableEdition extends Migration {
    public function up() {
        Schema::create('edition', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('volume');
            $table->text('cover')->nullable();
            $table->integer('number');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
        Schema::table('journal', function(Blueprint $table) {
            $table->foreign('id_edition')->references('id')->on('edition')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
        });
    }
    public function down() {
        Schema::table('journal', function(Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropForeign('journal_id_edition_foreign');
        });

        Schema::drop('edition');
    }
}
```

Journal table :

```
class CreateTableJournal extends Migration {
    public function up() {
        Schema::create('journal', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('title', 255);
            $table->text('abstract');
            $table->text('file');
            $table->integer('id_edition')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->string('journalslug');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
        Schema::table('journal', function(Blueprint $table) {
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
        });
    }
    public function down() {
        Schema::table('journal', function(Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropForeign('journal_user_id_foreign');
        });
        Schema::drop('journal');
    }
}
```

Users table :

```
class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('username')->unique();
            $table->string('userslug');
            $table->string('nameslug');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('phone')->nullable();
            $table->string('address')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->enum('level', ['admin', 'author']);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('users');
    }
}
```

Penulis table (pivot table to connect users table and journal table)

```
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('penulis', function (Blueprint $table) {
            // Create tabel penulis
            $table->integer('id_user')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->integer('id_journal')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->primary(['id_user', 'id_journal']);
            $table->foreign('id_user')
                  ->references('id')
                  ->on('users')
                  ->onDelete('cascade')
                  ->onUpdate('cascade');
            $table->foreign('id_journal')
                  ->references('id')
                  ->on('journal')
                  ->onDelete('cascade')
                  ->onUpdate('cascade');
        });
    }
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('penulis');
    }
}
```

-Edition table and Journal table has one-to-many relationship (one edition can have many journals)

-Users table and Journal table has multiple relationship, the first one is many-to-many relationship to enable a user tagging another user as one of the authors of the journal that he/she is going to upload. This relationship connected using a pivot table (penulis table). The second one is one-to-many relationship (one user has many journals) to make it possible that the user who uploaded the journal are the only one who can modify or deleting the journal (tagged users cannot).

Now back to the question, how to make this possible ? limiting the number of files that can be uploaded by users so that a user can only upload one journal in each edition. Below is my current controller to store the journal.

```
public function storejournal(JournalRequest $request) {
    $input = $request->all();
    $input['user_id'] = Auth::id();
    //Input PDF
    if ($request->hasFile('file')) {
        $input['file'] = $this->uploadPDF($request);
    }
    $id = $request->id;
    $journal = Edition::findOrFail($id)->journal()->create($input);
    $journal->user()->attach($request->input('penulis'));

    return redirect()->route('edition', ['id' => $id]);
}
```

If anyone can help that'd be great, thank you and sorry for my terrible English.

Comment: I agree it is important to provide a detailed question but it is as important to avoid superfluous information for the sake of clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use Laravel [Form Request Validator](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#form-request-validation) with [Exists](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#rule-exists) (not tested)

First, create the Form Request as such:

```
php artisan make:request JournalUserFormRequest
```

Then edit to check if the combination of `id_journal` and `id_user` already exists:

```
//JournalUserFormRequest
public function rules()
{
 $user = Auth::user();
 $edition = Edition::findOrFail($request->id)
    return [
        'id_journal' => [
            'required',
            Rule::exists('journal')->where(function ($query) {
                $query->where('id_user', $user->id)
                      ->where('id_edition', $edition->id);
            }),
        ],
    ]
}
```

You can then take the validated request and store it.

```
public function storejournal(JournalUserFormRequest $request) {

    $id = $request->id;
    $journal = Edition::findOrFail($id)->journal()->create($input);
    $journal->user()->attach($request->input('penulis'));

    return redirect()->route('edition', ['id' => $id]);
}
```

Comment: Haven't tried your solution yet, but this seems has nothing to do with edition. What I wanted is that a user can only upload one journal in each edition, doesn't mean that the user will no longer be able to upload a new journal. If a new edition added the user will be able to upload a new journal in the new edition. I've been thinking maybe I should create one-to-one relationship between users table and edition table, but again I'm confused with the store method and the validation

Comment: @AriandoMiller. That wasn't clear to me. The principle stays the same. I have made the edit. Here, I suggest that you validate your input by making sure that a given journal-user-edition record do not already exists before storing it. Your question is long and having a better summary of your problem could improve the quality as well as the number of answers.

Comment: that must be because of my English XD. Okay I got it, so I don't have to create relationship between users table and edition table ? I'll try this now

Comment: I was just trying to be specific that's why the question so long that I can write a book about it lol jk. I'm trying your solution now, brb